# Unique security scope number inside library

Tags: 2013, permissions, security, unique, scope

I have seen a [recommendation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx), that there should be no more security scopes than 5000:

> For most farms, we recommend that you consider lowering this limit to
>   5,000 unique scopes. For large lists, consider using a design that
>   uses as few unique permissions as possible. When the number of unique
>   security scopes for a list exceeds the value of the list view
>   threshold (set by default at 5,000 list items), additional SQL Server
>   round trips take place when the list is viewed, which can adversely
>   affect list view performance. A scope is the security boundary for a
>   securable object and any of its children that do not have a separate
>   security boundary defined. A scope contains an Access Control List
>   (ACL), but unlike NTFS ACLs, a scope can include security principals
>   that are specific to SharePoint Server 2013. The members of an ACL for
>   a scope can include Windows users, user accounts other than Windows
>   users (such as forms-based accounts), Active Directory groups, or
>   SharePoint groups.

The question is: how do we determine the number of unique security scopes inside document library? (maybe someone has a PS script for that?)

Example1
If we have one document with these **broken** permissions:

```
SPAdmins - contribute;
user1 - contribute, read;
SPReaders - read
```

How many unique security scopes do we have? 
3 ?
4 ?
other?

Example2
If we have one document with **broken** permissions(same as example1) inside folder with **inherited** permissions:

```
SPEditors - contribute;   
user5 - contribute, read;  
SPViewers - read
```

How many unique security scopes do we have overall?
3?
4?
6?
8?
other?

Example3
We have one document with **inherited** permissions inside folder with **inherited** permissions:

```
SPAdmins - contribute; 
user1 - contribute, read;
SPReaders - read
```

How many unique security scopes do we have overall?
3?
4?
6?
8?
other?

Example4
we have one document with **broken** permissions:

```
SPAdmins - contribute;
```

and another document with **broken** permissions in the same folder:

```
SPAdmins - contribute;
```

How many unique security scopes do we have overall?
2?
1?
other?

Comment: Check the official article (link below) that clearly explains what security scopes are in SharePoint 2013. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn169567.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If i've understood it correctly, security scope as the sum of all the access in a document.So, for your examples, you always have 1. My examples:

One list:

Two items broken permission can be seen by user a ---> 2 security scope

Two items broken permission can be seen by user b ---> 2 security scope

Two items broken permission can be seen by users a,b ---> 2 security scope

items broken permission can be seen by user a and modify by user b---> 2 security scope

Overall security scopes in the list: 8
You can read : https://www.martinhatch.com/2011/10/scaling-to-10000-unique-permissions.html and http://www.collabshow.com/2008/10/31/best-practices-for-enterprise-user-scalability-in-sharepoint/

Comment: We are looking for a powershell solution

Comment: https://www.morgantechspace.com/2017/09/find-sharepoint-list-items-with-unique-permission-powershell.html